# Evaluate the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n^2}\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}\frac{i-1/2}n\cdot\frac{j-1/2}n$

Tags: calculus

Why is $$\frac1{n^2}\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}\frac{i-1/2}n\cdot\frac{j-1/2}n$$
evaluated to $xy dx dy$ instead of $(x-\frac12)(y-\frac12) dx dy$? Where is the $\frac12$?
I don't understand why I can't post this question, can someone point me the direction of how to edit the question? I know what this equation is evaluated to I just want to know where the $\frac12$ goes.

Comment: Hello. At least you can evaluate this sum explicitly.

Comment: $1/2$ is divided by $n$ You have $\dfrac{i}{n}+\dfrac{1}{2n}$, the last term going to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac1{n^2}\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}\dfrac{i-1/2}n\cdot\frac{j-1/2}n=\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{i-1/2}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{j-1/2}{n^2}$$

So, we have twice this:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{j-1/2}{n^2}=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\dfrac{j}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{2n^2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^nj+\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{1}{2n^2}=$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2n}=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2n}+\dfrac{1}{2n}$$

Compare with,

$$\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{j}{n^2}=\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{j}{n^2}=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^nj=$$

$$=\dfrac{1}{n^2}\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2n}$$

But in the limit as $n\to\infty$ both expressions lead to $\dfrac{1}{2}$, the same limit, because the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ adds a quantity that vanishes at the limit So, into the Riemann sum you can simply drop the $\dfrac{1}{2}$